# Stack Pointer Register value for undefined stack (Assembly)

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, stack, cpu-registers

When a stack is not defined in an Assembly program, what does the Stack Pointer register SP point to (what value does it contain)?

Our (badly printed) school book says the following: "The SP register contains the adress of the last byte of the pile IF it is definied, if not, then the value 0, this means the last byte of the segment (2^16), knowing that the operation on the SP register is to decrement by 2, this gives us -2 = 0FFFE in Hexadecimal which is taken as the adress (non signed value)"

However, I think the paragraph is supposed to say "The SP register contains the adress of the last byte of the pile IF it is definied, if not, then the value 0, **knowing that the operation on the SP register is to decrement by 2, this gives us -2=0FFFE in Hexadecimal which is taken as the adress (non signed value), this means the last byte of the segment (2^16)**"

I have some questions about this and the SP in general:

- Why did they decrement SP, why not just leave it at 0?
- Why did they decrement by exactly **2**?
- Shouldn't the last byte of the segment be 0FFF**F** not 0FFF**E**?

Comment: Generally, if there is no stack, the stack pointer might contain anything.

Comment: The initial conditions depend on the operating system.